# Which Capistrano 3 directory structure should I use?

Tags: git, magento, capistrano3

I want to deploy a Magento application with Capistrano 3. Magento has a lib folder in the project root, so I don't think I should install Capistrano from the Magento project folder. I created a public folder. Now my project directory looks like this:

```
config/
lib/
public/
.git
.gitignore
Capfile
```

As you can see the Capistrano configuration, tasks and the project code are in 1 Git repository. I don't know if this is the way to go.

If I deploy this, it will also deploy the Capistrano files and folders which is not what I want.

Should I create my Git repository in the public folder?
Or should I move the contents from the public folder up one level?

I've been searching the internet for a while now but I cannot find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track capistrano deploy script in github but don't wish to upload it to production server, I would suggest that you separate out the capistrano into a separate project.  Othwerwise, I don't think it can be helped that capistrano code is deployed to production server.

If you really don't want the capistrano script to be there, then I would suggest that you create an additional task that simply deletes the capistrano folder on production.

Comment: I still think it's weird that Capistrano doesn't have a solution for this. But I'll just leave the Capistrano files on my remote server then. They don't take up much disk space and they are outside of the document root, so I don't think they would cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

In `.gitignore` file, you can enter the paths of the files which are not necessary for uploading. Which I mean is, suppose if you enter the `/lib` in the `.gitignore` file then those files will be ignored while creating a package to deploy from git. So enter the paths of the files which are not required. Go through this article http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: But then it would create a directory structure like {deploy_to}/current/public/.

Comment: No it will not create any new directory structure. It will just ignore the files in the same path which are not required

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. In the current directory, there would be 1 directory called public. In that directory all Magento code would reside. I don't want that, I want the Magento code to reside in the directory called current.

Comment: OK.. First copy the magento folder(which contains required code) to the public. Then it will be as public/magento/<required_code_files>.. Then enter into the Magento folder and select the folders & files which you require and MOVE those files to the public folder. Then your magento folder will be empty and you can delete if you want. Is this what you are searching for?

Comment: No. I will use Magento's index.php as example. On my local machine, the index.php file will be located at /var/www/demoshop/public/index.php. On my production machine, it will be at /var/www/demoshop/current/public/index.php with the current configuration. I want it to be at /var/www/demoshop/current/index.php. Then I would use the /var/www/demoshop/current directory as my document root. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you.. What is the word "current" means??